# Immutable objects with copyWithZone:

Tags: objective-c, copy

I was wondering why I'm still allowed to change `fracB` when it's referencing an immutable `Fraction` object made by `NSCopyWithZone:`?

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface Fraction : NSObject <NSCopying>
@property int numerator, denominator;

-(void) set: (int) n over: (int) d;
-(Fraction *) initWithValues: (int) n over: (int) d;

@end

@implementation Fraction
@synthesize numerator, denominator;

-(Fraction *) initWithValues:(int)n over:(int)d {
    self = [super init];

    if (self) 
        [self set:n over:d];

    return self;
}

-(void) set: (int) n over:(int)d {
    numerator = n;
    denominator = d;
}

-(Fraction *) copyWithZone:(NSZone *)zone {
    Fraction *copied = [[Fraction allocWithZone: zone] init];

    [copied set:numerator over:denominator];

    return copied;
}

@end
```

---

```
#import "Fraction.h"
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

int main (int argc, char *argv[])  
{  
    @autoreleasepool {  
        Fraction *fracA = [[Fraction alloc] initWithValues:5 over:5];
        Fraction *fracB = [[Fraction alloc] init];

        fracB = [fracA copy];
        [fracB set:2 over:2];

        NSLog(@"%@", fracB);
    }
    return 0;  
}
```

---

```
2012-08-07 20:01:04.248 prog[1972:707] 2/2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mutability is defined by the class, not by the method used to create the instance, not by the framework, and certainly not by the language. Only your own code can cause your class to be immutable.

More simply, if the class offers a setter method for some property, then you can set that property regardless of your use of `copy` or `mutableCopy`.

As the [`NSMutableCopying` docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSMutableCopying_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html) (whence comes the `mutableCopy` method) say,

> Only classes that define an “immutable vs. mutable” distinction should adopt this protocol.

If you want this distinction for your own class, the best way would be to make *two* classes, in the mold of `NSArray`/`NSMutableArray` or `NSString`/`NSMutableString`, where the mutable version is a subclass of the other. So you might have `Fraction` and `MutableFraction`.

Only `MutableFraction` would have the method `set:over:`; `Fraction` instances would require those values to be set when the object is created. You would then implement `mutableCopy` in `Fraction` to return an instance of `MutableFraction` (your implementation of `copy` can remain as is).

Answer (score 1):

Because your class is mutable. Objective-C doesn't know that you mean for it to be immutable--the language doesn't even know what immutability means. If your class has mutators (methods that cause its state or value to change), `NSCopying` won't make them go away.

If you want your class to be truly immutable, remove your mutator (`-set:over:`.) If you want a distinction between mutable and immutable objects, create a `MutableFraction` subclass and expose `-set:over:` only in that subclass.